# How to use Render Effect in Jetpack Compose？

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

ViewGroup:

```
mImageView?.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon)
mImageView?.setRenderEffect(RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(25f,25f, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR))
```

Compose:

```
Image(bitmap..)
```

**How can I do what I could with RenderEffect in Compose?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify it with [`Modifier.graphicsLayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).graphicsLayer(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.TransformOrigin,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.RenderEffect)):

```kotlin
Modifier.graphicsLayer(
    renderEffect = RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(25f,25f, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR).asComposeRenderEffect()
)
```